# Add file to web root when deploying Expo web project?

Tags: expo

I need a file to be added to the web root when I deploy my Expo web project (An Apple App Site Association file).

Is this functionality supported by Expo out the box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is make a folder called 'web' in the root of your project. Any files in there are moved to the web root when `expo build:web` is run

https://medium.com/@toastui/from-zero-to-publish-expo-web-react-native-for-web-tutorial-e3e020d6d3ff